# Hyper-V Dynamic Memory for Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, windows-10, ubuntu-15.10

I'm running the latest Windows 10 Pro Fall Update, and setup a guest OS of Ubuntu Desktop 64-Bit 15.10 in Hyper-V. I'm trying to use the dynamic memory feature, but Hyper-V wants to assign far more memory (5-10x) than the guest OS appears to be using:

[image: Hyper-V Assigned Memory and Guest OS Memory Usage]

In Hyper-V Manager

```
Startup Memory: 1024 MB
Dynamic Memory: Enabled
Minimum Memory: 1024 MB
Maximum Memory: 8192 MB
Assigned Memory: 4232 MB
Memory Demand: 3597 MB
```

In Guest OS, Ubuntu System Monitor

```
Memory
691 MiB (16%) of 4.1 GiB
Swap
0 bytes of 4.0 GiB
```

This is with Ubuntu just at the desktop, running top or system monitor. Bothy top and system monitor show no memory hogs, Compiz is the biggest user at ~210 MiB, everything else is 50 MiB or smaller.

The memory settings in Hyper-V for the VM are:

```
RAM:     1024 MB (Not sure if this is used when dynamic memory is turned on)
Min RAM: 1024 MB
Max Ram: 8192 MB
Memory Buffer: 20%
```

Answer (score 0):

System monitor is probably excluding the RAM used for caching.  Use 'free -m' on the command line to see how much is really used with and without caching.  It will likely be close to the 4GB assigned RAM.

Comment: After the VM has been idling in the background for a week, free -m shows `Mem: total 4205, used 1903, free 2302, shared 8, buffers 127, cached 786; Swap: total 4087, used 0, free 4087`, and then backing out the buffers and cache brings it to `988 used` and `3216 free`. Then in Hyper-V Manager at the same time: `Memory Demand: 3312 MB. Assigned Memory: 3944 MB`. So the cache/buffers make up for part of the discrepancy, but Hyper-V is still off by 1.3 GiB